# Postgresql regexp_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace

How can I replace any year from 1990-2050 with a space ?

I can replace any 4 digit number as follows

`select regexp_replace('sdfg 2000', '(\y(\d{4})\y)', '', 'g');`

But how additionally I can check the range?
Any help are welcome

Comment: With regex I don't think you can. Because restricting first digit to `1` and `2`  is possible. But other places cannot be restricted in that way. Better look for some way with programming.

Comment: It wasn't possible by range checking so I broke ranges to match with regex. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered an alternative way to solve your problem. Take a look.

You wish to replace year from `1990-2050`. Let's break that range into

1. `1990-1999`
2. `2000-2049`
3. `2050`

All three ranges can be matched by following regex.

**Regex:** `[1][9][9][0-9]|[2][0][0-4][0-9]|2050`

**Explanation:**

- `[1][9][9][0-9]` will match years from `1990` to `1999`.
- `[2][0][0-4][0-9]` will match years from `2000` to `2049`.
- `2050` will match `2050` literally
- `|` means alteration. It will check either of these three patterns.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC9aW4/1)**</kbd>

Comment: This can be simpler: `199[0-9]|20[0-4][0-9]|2050`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Yes that is one simple way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression to extract and test for the year and only replace if the year falls into the range you want:

```
with test_data (col1) as (
  values ('sdfg 2000'), ('foo 1983'), ('bar 2010'), ('bla 1940')
)
select col1, 
       case 
         when nullif(regexp_replace(col1, '[^0-9]+',''),'')::int between 1990 and 2050 
              then regexp_replace(col1, '\d{4}', '', 'g')
         else col1 
       end as replaced
from test_data;
```

Results in:

```
col1      | replaced
----------+---------
sdfg 2000 | sdfg    
foo 1983  | foo 1983
bar 2010  | bar     
bla 1940  | bla 1940
```

The `nullif(..)` is necessary for values that do not contain any numbers. If you don't have values like that, you can leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (emphasis mine):

> Each character in a regular expression (that is, each character in the
>   string describing its pattern) is understood to be: a metacharacter
>   (with its special meaning), or a regular character (with its *literal*
>   *meaning*).

In your case, the letters do not have literal meaning, their meaning depends on characters around it.